# Need Guidance Implementing OAuth 2.0 in ASP.NET App

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I have created an ASP.NET application and an Azure-AD domain.  Currently, I have the ASP.NET auth set up to hit the wsfed endpoint in Azure-AD.  Everything works fine, but the problem is that this issues a SAML token and I need a JWT.  From what I have read after much internet searching, I need to authenticate to the OAuth 2.0 endpoint of my Azure-AD domain.  The trouble with this is that with everything configured the way it is, I always get back a 400 from this endpoint, likely because my config file is all set up for fed auth.  My question is how do I configure my ASP.NET application so that it can talk to the OAuth 2.0 endpoint of my Azure-AD domain?

I need to use passive authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure AD supports the OAuth2.0 flow that you can execute once the user has signed in using passive authentication, to receive access tokens to make delegated calls to WebAPIs on behalf of the user. You can use the Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL SDK) to execute the OAuth flow. This sample application does exactly that: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/AAL-Server-to-Server-9aafccc1

However, for your scenario, we recommend the OpenId Connect flow now, instead of SAML SSO + OAuth. With Azure AD OpenIDConnect flow, the Web Application receives an SSO token (JWT id_token) using which it signs-in the user, and also receives an auth code (OAuth auth code) that it can redeem for an Access Token (JWT access token) to access WebAPIs on behalf of the user. Azure AD provides an OWIN component that does this. This sample application should see you through: https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-WebAPI-OpenIDConnect-DotNet

Finally, refer to this help topic to find all authentications flows supported and recommended by Azure AD for your Web Apps/APIs and Rich-Client/Mobile Apps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn499820.aspx

Hope this helps